# Migrate local user to LDAP server and keep the old user directory

Tags: ldap, directory, users, local, home-directory

I have an existing Debian server with a lot of local user (these user account are used for application authentication and keeps files in each home directory), and I want to migrate all the local user to LDAP.

I want all the user to still be able to access their home directory. and everytime I create new user in LDAP, it creates it's own home directory.

Is this possible? and how to do so?

What I have done :

- Setup LDAP Server.
- Migrate all user to LDAP with 3 seperate OU.

What I haven't finish doing

- Make other client authenticate user using LDAP

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup a nss to fetch information from ldap by adding the necessary info to `/etc/ldap.conf` and enabling ldap in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` then you should be all set. The location of the home directory is not affected by whether the information comes from `/etc/passwd` or from your ldap server.

To make authentication work you also need to update the pam config in `/etc/pam.d`